# Mongodb strategy for Multi-Company web app

Tags: performance, mongodb, security, meteor, digital-ocean

I am developing a web app in Meteor, with Mongo, that will be running on cloud. Each user must belong to a Company. 
Each Company can only access it's own data.
Each user can access it's own data and some data shared with other users of the same company.
Imagine **1.000 companies and 100 users per company**, it could get very bad in performance and secutiry, if I use 1 Mongodb database for whole app.

So, because Mongo is "Schema-less and Database-less" I think I can define 1.000 dbs, lets say **db_0001**, **db_0002**, ... with same name collections, lets say **tasks**, **messages**, ..., so the app can be efficient and more secure (same code for every Company and isolation of data).

Also, on **hosting side** (let's say for example with Digital Ocean), I think its easier to distribute the dbs if the are already atomized.

Is this a good approach? Or should I not worry about it and let the hosting do this job?

Any thoughts are wellcome.

Comment: Mongo will still be performant at 100k users, 1000 db instances sounds like overkill and not very scalable to me.

Comment: That's not how you scale Mongodb; you're going to create a giant hairball for yourself.  Start by reading https://www.mongodb.com/mongodb-scale and the links from there. There are many good online case studies of scaling Mongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently only looking at one side of the coin. That's fine to start with.

Think about how you are going to be displaying that data and what query does it translate to. Do a thorough due diligence on all the potential query. For example, how often would user/getbyid be called and how often would you have to show a user their info and their relationship with other users. What other meta data would be required beside user info, would you have to perform a join to get that data? or is it stored as an embedded document? What fields are you going to be searching and sorting by most? Which types of data are write heavy and what are read heavy?

Now lets get back to your database shading approach. It's great that you are thinking ahead of time on this front rather than having to rewrite your component later. Data volume/storage does not worry me here. How many concurrent users would be using at application and what are primary use cases should be the first place to look at to think about scale.

Additionally, you need to understand the nature of the business and project growth. Is it like Instragram type of hyper growth? or is it more predictable. A big Mongo cluster can handle thousands of concurrent read/write requests (assuming your design and query are optimized) so that does not bother me. If you want to keep it flexible MongoDB has a sharding mechanism and you can shard on a key and it takes care all the fancy stuff for ya.

MongoDB has eventual consistency (look up MongoDB CAP theorem) if you enable read from secondaries and you have a high volume business critical app you need to be careful because you can be reading out of date result.

As far as hosting is concerned, DO is fine but always have a backup in another region to maintain geographic redundancy so in case if a region goes down (Hello AWS!) you have something to fall back on.

Good luck on your project!

Comment: Thanks a lot Kalagen! Here is a short list of what I am going to use for my design: 1) Include a company_id in every collection and an index on that field, 2) Redundancy for attributes used a lot (i.e. user_id  user_name + user_url_pic allways stored), 3) Joining collections that has separate meaning or volume (i.e. Projects and Meetings), 4) Data Dictionary for every field (avoid 2 fields with same name and different meaning), 5) Separate collections (for performance) if possible (instead of 'animals', preffer 'lions', 'dogs', ...). I will be posting this as an answer if no further comments.